# Webcam support for Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I open the webcam using Safari Browser on a desktop computer, using html5 or javascript?
It seems `navigator.getUserMedia()` from javascript is not working in Safari.
I found a library like WebRTC project but, Safari browser is not supported.
Could anyone help me please?

Comment: flash or java may be able to do it. Safari still don't support getUserMedia...

Comment: You can use temasys plugin,It support webrtc IE and safari include Media API,Datachannel API,Peerconnection API here https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/WebRTC+Plugins

Comment: did you find any result regarding this. I having same issue.

Comment: nothing yet @Chaitanya, ended up removing that feature for Safari. I think it's still in development

Comment: yesterday i just found the way to how to do it

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.getUserMedia()` is deprecated in for new browser.
Try to used like this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
```

Here is my whole code

```
<script>
// Older browsers might not implement mediaDevices at all, so we set an empty object first
 var video = document.querySelector('video');
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var image = document.querySelector('img');
if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices = {};
}

// Some browsers partially implement mediaDevices. We can't just assign an object
// with getUserMedia as it would overwrite existing properties.
// Here, we will just add the getUserMedia property if it's missing.
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraints) {

    // First get ahold of the legacy getUserMedia, if present
    var getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    // Some browsers just don't implement it - return a rejected promise with an error
    // to keep a consistent interface
    if (!getUserMedia) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
    }

    // Otherwise, wrap the call to the old navigator.getUserMedia with a Promise
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
    });
  }
}
function snapshot() {
      var cw = video.clientWidth;
      var ch = video.clientHeight;
      ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, cw, ch, 0, 0, cw / 2, ch / 3);
      image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
      image.height = ch;
      image.width = cw;
  }

  video.addEventListener('click', snapshot, false);
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: false, video: true })
.then(function(stream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  // Older browsers may not have srcObject
 // if ("srcObject" in video) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
 // } else {
    // Avoid using this in new browsers, as it is going away.
    //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
 // }
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    video.play();
  };
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
});
</script>
```